# Factory Class vs. Proxy Class in magento2

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, object-manager

I read [here](http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2016/01/27/dependency-injection-in-magento-2/), there are two types of classes available in Magento 2.  Injectible and Non-injectible.

To inject a non-injectible object as dependency, we use `Factory Class`.

> For example

`Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`  is non-injectible.  That’s because it is a model that relies on data from the database.  In order to be able to inject this as a dependency, we will use Factory Class.

But what is the purpose of `Proxy Class` and in which scenario, we need to use `Proxy Class`

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Proxy classes are intended to increase object creation speed.
For example you want to create an object of the class where a lot of another classes are created in the constructor via dependency injection. Maybe you won't use those classes but they are created and some of them can take some time to be created.

To avoid such a scenario Proxy objects exists. The proxy object completely replaces the constructor of the proxied object, and does not make a parent::__construct call. In this way you avoid creation all the classes in the constructor.
Instead Proxy objects have constructor with three parameters

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager, $instanceName = '\\Pulsestorm\\TutorialProxy1\\Model\\SlowLoading', $shared = true)
{
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_instanceName = $instanceName;
    $this->_isShared = $shared;
}
```

The first is an object manager instance, the second is the name of the class this object proxies, and the third is a shared argument.

So, by replacing the entire constructor, we avoid any slow loading behavior.

Each method of original object is override by proxy object. Just string `$this->_getSubject()` is added that create instance of original object! In this way you call constructor of original object only when it's needed. Something like lazy loading.

Recommend you to read [excellent post about proxy objects](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_proxy_objects)

Comment: Using proxies can optimize your application by only loading resources which are required. We don't need to create an object for each class which is passed to __construct().

Answer (score 2):

Proxy classes use for lazy creation of object (on first method call). See more information in [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/proxies.html)

Comment: Hello @kAndy,please reply my question  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/266014/24878